# What is the longest directory and file name?

Tags: windows, file, directory, size

I need to optimize my Java application that works with directories and files. I use `String[] buffer;` to keep file or dir name. So what's the longest possible file or dir name allowed in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename with path to the file is limited to 260 characters.

Comment: Note that this is an implementation detail.  Windows can handle paths longer than that, if the application supports it, and while the current version of Java does not future versions might.